# Cannot upload application through Play Store - Rollout Button Disabled

Tags: android, google-play

[image: Sample 1]

I am trying to upload my app to the Play Store. I've met all of the requirements and all of them got a green tick. However, the `rollout to production` button is still disabled.

Can someone help? I really don't know what the problem is here.

Comment: i upvoted your question, now you can place image, please help us help you